# Have To Render Image Before Title Of Section,Category Article

Tags: joomla

How can I display a separate image before the title of each section, category and article (image be different)?

I.e. is there a way through admin plugin or some way so that I could render it easily?

I am using Joomla 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the image. If you mean an icon or small image in front of the saction/category/title then you could do that with CSS and the page class suffix to determine which image displays on which page.

If you mean more like a header image, then you would probably need to do it in a module and assign the module to the page you want to place it in. You'd need a module per image doing it this way.

You could also add the image to the section or category description, then use a template override to place the image where you want it.

On one site we built we have a unique header image on every page. We did it with a module and K2. Again, it depends on what you are trying to do. You would need to give more details to get a specific answer.

Comment: i actually wanted to display an image before the title of section/category/article. e.g. IMAGE then TITLE then Content. At the article level i have done it by adding a parameter in advance parameter section that enables me to show image at top of title but unable to do same in section and category if u briefly give me an example. it be a plugin, administrative plugin, or any other way

Comment: I would very seriously consider moving your content in to a CCK rather than hacking the Joomla core. K2 gives you the ability to assign an image to every category and content item, then display either, neither, or both or any combination you need. I prefer K2 but Zoo, Seblod, Flexicontent and others all have the ability to associate an image with a content item.